# Exporting Sharp Map map to Shape File (.shp)

Tags: sharpmap

**Decription :**  I read Data from PostGreSQL and display it on SharpMap using SharpMap Library.

**What i want** I want to export SharpMap map into ShapeFile (.shp). How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

SharpMap cannot write ShapeFiles. Use GDAL.